# List of Figures - how to add caption label

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tocloft

I'm using the `caption` package. 
In the List-Of-Figures I get only the numbers, but I also want to have the prefix.
It currently looks like that:

> List of Figures
>   1 Caption of Figure 1........1
>   2 Caption of Figure 2........9

And I want it to look like:

> List of Figures
>   Figure 1: Caption of Figure 1...1
>   Figure 2: Caption of Figure 2...9

The same format is already used for the captions themselves.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the [`tocloft` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft); an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you want `tocloft` to use default LaTeX formatting (so it won't "mess up" for example the layout of your table of contents and so on) you can use the titles option of the package:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

Comment: This works well, except that tocloft seems to ruin the format of LOF and LOT. But I will figure that out.   Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15):

To achieve what you're aiming for *without* loading the `tocloft` package, one has to patch an instruction in LaTeX's internal `\@caption` macro and redefine the internal macros `\l@figure` and `\l@table`.

The following MWE shows how to do this; note that the patching is done with the command `\patchcmd` provided by the `etoolbox` package. (If, for some reason, you don't want to use the `\patchcmd` instruction, you will need to copy and paste the entire definition of `\@caption` from the file `latex.ltx` into your preamble and replace the string `\csname the#1\endcsname` with `\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:`, leaving the other instructions unchanged.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{A figure}
\centering xyz
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Some table}
\centering abc
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would want _not_ to use `tocloft`?

Comment: @MartinSchröder well, it's giving me an error in Overleaf when I try to use it.

Comment: @Seanny123 - Please provide more information about the document class you use, how you load the `tocloft` package, and the error(s) you get.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't effect with longtable. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Yuri - Please tell me how you start a `longtable` environment. Also, which document class do you use?

Comment: I replace table by longtable and remove option [h] in your MWE above. You can try on this :D

Comment: @Yuri - What exactly do you mean by "replace"? Are you simply writing `\begin{longtable}`? If so, there's **zero chance** of success. You must write something like `\begin{longtable}{llll}`, where `llll` is the column specification. Do please familiarize yourself with the syntax of the `longtable` environment.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I begin longtable with `\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}}` and finish with `\end{longtable}`. Don't forget use `longtable` package. I have a result without "Table" word in List of tables.

Comment: @Yuri - Based on the fragmented pieces of information you've provided so far, I have neither a good enough idea of what's going on nor a solid understanding of what you're trying to achieve. Please post a **new query** to state what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56909/discussion-between-yuri-and-mico).

Comment: @Yuri - I don't think this is something that can be solved in the chat room. That's why I asked you to take the time to put together a new query.

Comment: This doesn't work if hyperref is used.

Comment: @Joseph - The solution I posted works *just fine* with `hyperref` as long as `hyperref` is loaded last -- which one should pretty much always to anyway. The main exception is the `cleveref` package, which must be loaded after `hyperref`.

Comment: @Mico Your solution didn't work for me for some reason...

Comment: @DGuys - Sorry, but a claim such as "[y]our solution didn't work for me for some reason" is *not actionable*. Please be a lot more specific as to what isn't working. Did you get any error and/or warning messages? If so, what do these messages say? Do you maybe use a nonstandard document class?

Answer (score 7):

When you caption your figure, there's an optional argument that's designed for the list of figures.

```
\caption[short title]{Long caption describing the figure.}
```

This will display the short title as the title in the list of figures, and the long caption as the actual caption of your figure.
It is perfectly acceptable for these both to be the same.

It is designed this way as many figures, particularly in scientific publications have long captions describing everything that is in the figure.
All of this wouldn't fit into the list of figures, so there is a separate title for that purpose.

It is optional because you don't need it if you are not including a list of figures.

Comment: Just noticed that you're using the caption package, what I have described is the default. I would guess that the syntax for the caption package is similar (if not exactly the same).

Comment: a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Thank you very much @Dom, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry @MiKa, just re-read, and realised I hadn't understood the question, oh well. Thanks for the pointer on how to make it look like code @Hendrik Vogt.

Comment: no problem, luckily somebody found a solution to my problem. Thanks for trying!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Or with a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrartcl}% loads tocbasic automatically
\AfterTOCHead[lof]{\def\autodot{:}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to do this with tables we well?

Comment: @AustinBenny Of course it is possible with tables as well. In the first example you have to add `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename}, dynnumwidth,  numsep=1em]{tocline}{table}` and in the second (using a KOMA-Script class) `\AfterTOCHead[lot]{\def\autodot{:}}`.