# How to align the captions in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, indentation

How to align the captions in the list of figures ?

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\renewcommand*\cftfigpresnum{Figure~}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{\cftfigpresnum}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnumb}{\quad~~}
```

This code produces:

> Figure 1 xxxxxxxxxxxx....34
>
> Figure 2 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
>               yyyyy.........................35

I would like to change to look like this:

> Figure 1 xxxxxxxxxxxx....34
>
> Figure 2 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
>                  yyyyy......................35

The problem I want to solve is to remove any "YYY" below the term "Figure 2" and align up with the above caption just when it starts.

Comment: I borrowed the answer from the great **Tom** at http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables-listoffigures-listoftables/#comment-3281


My code should be:

\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand*\cftfigpresnum{Figure~}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: your comment is really an answer.  if you enter it as an answer, i'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Solution by Tom and Gonzalo in [List of Figures - how to add caption label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label), as commented by the OP:

```
\newlength{\mylen}
\renewcommand*\cftfigpresnum{Figure~}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
```