# How do I control the space between the figure number (or table number) and the caption on the list of figures (list of tables) page?

Tags: table-of-contents

On my list of figures and list of tables pages there is no space between the figure number (or table number) and the caption. I would like to control this spacing. I would also like to control the alignment of the caption. So if the caption runs into other lines then these should be aligned with the first line. How can I control these?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Do you use any related packages?

Comment: I am using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}`   \usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }

Comment: *click*->[**minimal working example (MWE)**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)<-*click*

Comment: I am using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}`   `\usepackage{tocloft}`  
`\begin{document}`
`\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }`
`\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }` `\begin{document}`

Comment: Does the linked question help?

Comment: @Daniel I am looking at it to see which parts I can take out.

Comment: @Daniel. The following `\newlength{\mylenf}` 
`\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+3.5em}`
`\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+3.5em}`  helped to control the spacing. Can you give a suggestion to control the alignment of the caption when it runs into other lines?

Comment: This should be happened. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: @Daniel maybe this will help. The alignment for the caption was ok before I used `\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }` to insert the words Figure and Table before the figure (table) number.

Comment: @PeterPalmer *don't* use `\cftfigfont` and `\cfttabfont` to add the words "Figure" and "Table" (those commands are only meant to change font attributes). Use these instead: `\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Figure\ }
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table\ }

\newlength\mylenf
\settowidth\mylenf{\cftfigpresnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylenf}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\mylenf}`

Comment: @Medina Thank you. When I use your code the alignments are correct but the words "Figure" and "Table" are not present before the figure or table number. I get the error messages `\cftfigpresnum` undefined and `\cfttabpresnum` undefined. The following code found at [link](http://http://http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label/12869#12869) solves the problem `\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{7.0em}} 
\let\l@table\l@figure 
\makeatother`.