# How to add the word "Figure" to the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I have a problem when trying to add the word "Figure" before the actual number in the list of figures. I guess it will be the same for all languages, since the langauge setting will make it in my language automatically. But what I have so far is only the number like the upper line, and it should be like the second line (which was poorly made with paint, just in case you wonder).

[image]

Here is the code I am using for figures so far:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{imageName.png}
\caption[CaptionText]{CaptionText\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{CaptionTextn. Available under \url{www.nowhere.com}, seen on Date.}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12869/828. This seems to exactly do what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple method that works in this case.

Replace

```
\listoffigures
```

with

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the option demo in your document

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{imageName.png}
\caption[CaptionText]{CaptionText\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{CaptionTextn. Available under \url{www.nowhere.com}, seen on Date.}

{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: How do I add a solon after figure name? For instance, Figure 3.1: <figure caption>

Comment: @fatih To achieve this, you have to use the `tocloft` package or patch the `\@caption` command. See the answers in the duplicate question.

Comment: Doesn't work well for cases where caption is spread over two lines.