# Add the word “Figure”/"Table" to lof/lot: Past solution alters format

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tocloft

I am new to the forum. Hopefully my question is within standards.

I want to add the word “Figure”/"Table" in front of each caption in the lof/lot. I tried this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155202/124927

And it worked perfectly. Well, almost.

The thing is that now the format in my lof/lot is slightly altered. It messes up the indentation in the captions that are long enough to require two lines, as in:
[image]

I am aware of the package tocloft. The problem is that the simple fact of loading it (as `[subfigure]{tocloft}`) in turn messes up the formatting of the lof and lot. The formatting needs to be consistent in all of the thesis.

I am using a customized class (not report , etc.) for the formatting of my school (created by somebody some time ago) which starts like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/09/24]
\ProvidesPackage{sgpPhDstyle}
```

Is there any way to keep the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155202/124927, while keeping the formatting of the lof/lot? Maybe a clever re-definition of `\listoffigures`?

Thanks a lot in advance to anybody that can give me an answer.

EDIT2:
Ok, here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \begin{document}
    {
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
    \listoffigures
    }   
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Figures} 
    \cleardoublepage

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \caption{this is a really loooooooooooooooooooooooooong figure captionthat will take up two lines in the List of Figures.} 
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a MWE.

Comment: You can try to achieve a MWE by just transferring your document to `article class`, adding one figure with a long title and the `\listoffigures` command. Add as many lines of code as needed to reproduce the error and post that code.

Answer (score 2):

`tocloft` provides better ways to use such a `figure` prefix, but the best way is to use `caption` and defining a new caption list format for `figure` and `table`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{30pt}% More space
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{30pt}% More space


\usepackage{pgffor}

\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figprefix}{#1\figurename~#2}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{tabprefix}{#1\tablename~#2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figprefix}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=tabprefix}


\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \caption{this is a really loooooooooooooooooooooooooong figure caption that will take up two lines in the List of Tables.}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{this is a really loooooooooooooooooooooooooong figure caption that will take up two lines in the List of Tables.} 
  \end{table}


}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. In my actual code (with the class I mentioned, with which I can't really get a MWE), this solution does add the word "Figure"/"Table" but does not solve the indentation issue. In addition, it causes the word Figure"/"Table" to overlap the list entries.

Comment: I don't have your class at hand. It is possible to change the `\cftfigindent` etc. lenghts, but class templates glued together by people apparently without any understanding of LaTeX mess up the whole affair!