# Figure caption in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Example picture}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Is it possible to get Figure prefix in list of figures like shown in this image:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: See the `caption` package and its `\captionsetup` macro.

Comment: Seems like this works:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155177/how-to-add-the-word-figure-to-the-list-of-figures