# Lyx - List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I am using LyX and the report class. (KOMA-Script).
My **List of Figures** just prints the figure number and its caption but not the word **Figure** infront.
How could I modify the command in the Latex preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/, you can probably use the preamble in the accepted answer directly in LyX.

Comment: Great!! Adding the tocloft package and redefining the command solved it! Thanks a lot Torbjørn!

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use the KOMA-Option `listof=entryprefix`. There are to possibilities:

```
\documentclass[listof=entryprefix]{scrreprt}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{listof=entryprefix}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{listof=entryprefix}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure one}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test figure two}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```