# How to change enumeration in List of Figures to 'Fig.X'?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, tocloft

I want to change the numbers in my List of Figures from '1, 2, 3' to Fig.1, Fig.2, Fig.3 but I have no real idea how to do that.
I found this command but have no idea where to put it in my script or if it even works:

```
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\listoffigures
```

Does anyone have an Idea?

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=35mm,rmargin=25mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label helps.