# Delete number of figures in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

How to delete number of figures in the list of figures? I use `\listoffigures` and `\captionof`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE of your code. It helps us help you (e.g. to not suggest packages incompatible to your documentclass etc.).

Comment: IIRC, the figure number is added by \caption as part of the label field, not a separate argument to \addcontentsline.  Easy solution is to use an empty [short caption] argument and write your own \addcontentsline.

Answer (score 2):

The generic function that sets the number of content in a ToC (that also includes the LoF and LoT) is `\numberline`. It takes a single argument which holds the number of the entry being set. Manipulating this macro to ignore it's argument around the LoF is easy enough with the following:

```
\let\oldnumberline\numberline% Copy \numberline into \oldnumberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\oldnumberline{}}% Remove number argument
\listoffigures% Set the List of Figures
\let\numberline\oldnumberline% Restore \numberline (if needed)
```

[image]

Note that the argument removal still sets the figure entries away from the margin, because the figure number is set in a box of predetermined width. If you want that removed as well, use the `\numberline` macro to insert a negative space:

```
\let\oldnumberline\numberline% Copy \numberline into \oldnumberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{\hspace*{-1.5em}}% Remove number argument
\listoffigures
\let\numberline\oldnumberline% Restore \numberline (if needed)
```

[image]

The space between the number and the title in the LoF is `1.5em` (by default).

Comment: _ @Werner Can I achieve the format `Figure NumberPeriod` by modifying the above arguments.. For example if the figure number is 3.2 it should be shown as Figure 3.2. in the list of figures

Comment: @mert: Consider [this code](https://pastebin.com/Hd7L5AbR). It uses [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) to insert `Figure` before the number and a period `.` after the number, also adjusting the width of this new "figure number" to match. It uses content from [List of Figures - how to add caption label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12869/5764) (an FAQ).