# Centering the sentence in the table of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

I have a problem when adding the word "Figure" at the beginning of table of content. However there is a conflict here. [image]

I want it to appear like this;

[image]

I used following codes here;

I replaced

```
\listoffigures
```

with

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%

\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%

\listoffigures%

}
```

Besides, the codes of my figures were in the following form.

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{driscoll.png}

\end{center}

\caption{Three algebraic habits of mind}

\label{fig:driscoll.png}

\end{figure}
```

Ok, I tried to adopt tocloft package, but I could not understand how to change code of my figures?

My codes seems like this;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{styles/fbe_tez}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % To use Unicode (e.g. Turkish) characters

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

 % Some extra symbols

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{longtable}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Graphics will be here

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

%\pagestyle{empty}

%\includeonly{introduction} % To only process the given file

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{caption} 

\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{slashbox}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array,longtable}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{afterpage}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\begin{figure}[htpb]

\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{driscoll.png}

\end{center}

\caption{Three algebraic habits of mind}

\label{fig:driscoll.png}

\end{figure}

But, I need to change it to;

\begin{figure}[!ht]

\centering

\rule{2cm}{2cm}

\caption{test figure one}

\label{fig:test1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to change my codes into this one?

Comment: Why not use the `tocloft` package as shown in this answer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12869/134144

Comment: I could not manage to adopt the codes into my article. But if you strongly suggested it, i will give a try.

Comment: why don't you use short tags in the LoF, e.g. `\caption[bird in the sky]{a very nice figure, that shows a bird in the sky}` leading to

`List of Figure: 1.1 Bird in the Sky....9`

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Can you please add the document class and all packages and settings regarding the List of Figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two suggestions assuming that there are no settings regarding the TOC, LOF or LOT in the `fbe_tez.sty` (we do not have this package). Note that I have removed all packages which are not related to the issue.

With package **`tocbasic`**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Three algebraic habits of mind}
\label{fig:driscoll.png}
\end{figure}

But, I need to change it to;

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

Or with **package `tocloft`** as already suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12869/43317):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Three algebraic habits of mind}
\label{fig:driscoll.png}
\end{figure}

But, I need to change it to;

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Additional remarks:

There is no class option `onesided`. Maybe you want `oneside`, but this is default for `report`.

Do not load packages twice, eg. `graphicx`, `array`, `longtable`, `inputenc`. If you load `graphicx` then `graphics` is not needed.

Do not use `center` environment inside a float. Use the switch `\centering` instead.

Comment: It fits very well!