# patchcmd with if condtion

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, patching

I've had the problem, that I needed a prefix in my list of  figures/tables, but fortunately I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label) solution. I work with the `fancyhdr` package, so I need the `tocloft` package with the `title` option. I use it for my list of symbols and equations only. But no bad, because I make use of the code from "Mico" (same thread):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother
```

It works basically, but the list shows all figures/tables, even the ones who are hidden with `\caption[]{example}`:

[image: Screenshot]

This is a huge problem, that I can't solve. I'm a LaTeX beginner, but I think the `\patchcdm` just need a condition?! Any ideas?

---

Edit 1: Adding an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{list this figure}
\centering show
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption[]{don't list this figure}
\centering hide
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[h]
\caption[]{don't list this table}
\centering hide
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{list this table}
\centering show
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot Example]

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`? And welcome!

Comment: All figures/tabels which should not be seen, will be at the end of the document. So unlike shown in the example, you may not worry about blank spaces above or betwenn other list elements.