# How to add the "Figure XX" and "Table XX" numbering in the List of Figures and tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, report

Currently my LoT and LoF only shows numbers and short captions e.g

```
    2.1 Bathimety map.....1
    2.2 Other stuff ......2
```

But I would like to have them listed in the LoF and LoT as

```
    Figure 2.1 Bathimetry map......1
    Figure 2.2 Other stuff.........2

    Table 1.1 Cool stuff...........3
```

**What do I need to change in my code (report class with chapters)?**

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm,paperwidth=22cm,tmargin=25.4mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=38.1mm,rmargin=25.4mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,siunitx,pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,wasysym,paralist,textcomp}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
%\tocsection
%\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
%\endgroup}
%\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
%\tocsection
%\tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
%\endgroup}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\newpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{ 
\includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{Map.png}}
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\caption[Bathymetry map ]{\textbf{Bathymetry}}
\label{fig.B1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/list-of-figures-how-to-add-caption-label

Comment: Off-topic: Do get rid of (or comment out) the material between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, do get rid of the statement `\usepackage{caption}`, and do change `\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}` to `\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}`. Making these changes will let you change `\caption[Bathymetry map ]{\textbf{Bathymetry map}}` to `\caption{Bathymetry map}`.

Comment: @user133467 - Since you load the `caption` package, I can see no reason for basically ignoring its machinery in favor of some very low-level mucking around with `\@caption`. I'm also comfortable claiming that `\caption{Bathymetry map}` is a lot easier to maintain than `\caption[Bathymetry map ]{\textbf{Bathymetry map}}` is. Of course, you're entirely free to either increase or decrease the value of the third argument of the `\cftsetindent` directives.

Comment: Awesome, THANKS A LOT!!! This solved all my issues, I understand that your fix on the [labelfont=bf| vs [font=bf] lets me ignore all \textbf commands in each caption - significantly easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add the following code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\figurename\ }
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename\ }
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{4.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{4em}
```

Adding this code at the end of the preamble of the OP's test document and recompiling the test document twice yields the following result for the List of Figures page:

[image]